# Create signup form on site B which registers on site A

Tags: wordpress, iframe, registration, buddypress

Let me be more specific. I have a main social networking site, Site A. I also have a site which partners with site A, Site B.

Both sites are Wordpress Sites. Site A runs buddypress.

I obviously have a registration form on site A.

What i need is an identical procedure on Site B, which registers the user on Site A. Don't worry its made very obvious to the users, i'm not trying to dupe them :)

Currently i am using an Iframe to achieve this, but it really sucks.

Has anyone ever tried this or have an idea of a better way of dealing with it?

Cheers

Comment: If both sites are on the same server then you could make a multisite. More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network. If you are interested I'll give more information

Answer (score 0):

If both sites are on the same server then you could make a multisite.
More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network.
On a multi site it's just a setting to register on both sites